# How to use ion-autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using `ion-autocomplete` in my project and here is what I want to do:

Here is the input field:

```
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">    
    <span class="input-label">Multiple select autocomplete</span>
    <input ion-autocomplete type="text" readonly="readonly" 
           class="ion-autocomplete" autocomplete="on"
           ng-model="model"
           item-value-key="lastname"
           item-view-value-key="firstname"
           items-method="getTestItems(query)"
           items-method-value-key="items"
           placeholder="Enter test query ..."
           items-clicked-method="itemsClicked(callback)"
           items-removed-method="itemsRemoved(callback)" />
</label>
```

Here is the controller:

```
$scope.getTestItems =function (query) {
    if (query) { 
        return { 
            items: [ 
                {"matricule":"5324", "id":270, "lastname":"IZIKKI", "firstname"‌​:"SAID"}, 
                {"matricule":"5505", "id":271, "lastname":"BOUKASIM", "firstnam‌​e":"EL MAACHI"},
                {"matricule":"5505", "id":272, "lastname":"BELMOUMENE‌​", "firstname":"MHAME‌​D"} 
            ] 
        }; 
    } 
    return {
        items: []
    };
};
```

What I want to do is, I want to do search by matricule. In other words, when I type `5324`, I want to the last name and the first name associate to this matricule appear in the list. When I click <kbd>done</kbd>, I want to that appear in the model.

How can I achieve that please?

Comment: $scope.getTestItems =function (query) {
 
    if (query) {
      return {
        items: [         {"matricule":"5324","id":270,"lastname":"IZIKKI","firstname":"SAID"},
          {"matricule":"5505","id":271,"lastname":"BOUKASIM","firstname":"EL MAACHI"},{"matricule":"5505","id":272,"lastname":"BELMOUMENE","firstname":"MHAMED"}     
       
        ]
      };
    }
    return {items: []};
  };

Comment: heres the controllers above

Comment: Paste your code in post, not in comment. Go to the stackoverflow tour.

Comment: You are trying to do? which it is the error you get ??? Because it would be easy to do this with ng-repeat and filter